# Enviar objeto de componente padre a hijo llega undefined

Tags: reactjs

Para este ejemplo tengo 2 componentes:

```
- NewSilobagePage.tsx (Padre)
- CardComponent (Hijo)
```

En el componente Padre, creo un `useState()`  y le asigno el valor inicial "alta"

```
const [AltaEditar, setAltaEditar] = useState("Alta")
```

éste `useState()` NO se está utilizando ni modificandoen ningun lado, solo lo utilizo de ejemplo (lo uso para saber si estoy enviando bien las props ya que estoy practicando)

Desde el componente Padre estoy enviandole al hijo el valor de ese useState() asi:

```
    <CardComponent
      AltaEdit = {AltaEditar}
    >
```

Y asi recibo en CardComponent:

```
    const CardComponent = (props: any) => {
      const navigate = useNavigate();
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      const {
        AltaEdit
      } = props;
  console.log("AltaEdit " + AltaEdit)
    ....
    }
```

Aclaración: El componente Hijo SI está declarado en el componente Padre

El problema es que AltaEdit está llegando undefined y no sé porqué.

Si refresco la pagina me aparecen muchos console.log() cuando solamente lo tengo una vez:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como debo enviar correctamente desde el componente Padre a Hijo?

Comment: Parece que estas usando react-router, ¿Que versión?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",

Comment: Elimina `useNavigate` y `useDispatch` de `CardComponente` intenta de nuevo. Parece que no puedes usar ese patron en react router, recuerda que CardComponent debe ser llamado desde un Route component

Comment: Puedes mostrar tus importaciones

Comment: que extraño, a mí me funciona bien, asumiendo que el resto del código (que no vemos) no tenga errores